# How can I remove bluetooth-applet in 11.10?

Tags: bluetooth

I tried adding `rfkill block bluetooth` to /etc/rc.local. This did not work.

I tried adding both `blacklist bluetooth` and `blacklist btusb` to etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. This did not work.

So I went to Synaptic to remove it altogether, but when I marked bluez for removal it said it was going to also remove gnome-shell as well! So naturally I didn't do that.

(Is it sane to run a potential security problem like bluetooth by default? And why is something like that so tightly integrated into Gnome shell?)

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this annoying and unnecessary process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `cd /etc/xdg/autostart && sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' bluetooth-applet.desktop && sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' bluetooth-applet-unity.desktop` then going in to startup applications and unchecking the box? reference [here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/how-to-view-and-disable-hidden-startup.html).

Adding the rfkill stuff, should cause any bluetooth devices to not associate.  So your "security problem" is solved.

The applet Is just an indicator.  The Network-Manager applet still starts if it's not managing any interfaces.

The steps above will let you turn off the applet though.